# On a paper of von Neumann

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $T: H \to H$ be a contraction. In [Eine Spektraltheorie für allgemeine Operatoren eines unitären Raumes](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?agg_journal_Math.%20Nachr.=Math.%20Nachr.&batch_title=Selected%20Matches%20for%3A%20Items%20authored%20by%20von%20Neumann%2C%20John&fmt=doc&pg1=INDI&r=1&s1=208336&searchin=&sort=newest&vfpref=html), von Neumann proved the inequality
$$
\lVert p(T)\rVert \leq \sup \{\lvert p(z)\rvert:\lvert z\rvert \leq 1\},
$$
where $p$ is a polynomial. I am trying to understand some context behind this result (or why this could be useful in analysis), but not very successfully because the original paper is written in German. In particular, if this has any connection with (or applications to) quantum mechanics, which von Neumann was trying to formalize, I would be interested to hear about them! Sorry for the slightly vague question and thanks in advance!

Comment: See also https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Spectral_set .

Comment: It's Problem 180 in Paul R. Halmos, A Hilbert Space Problem Book .

Comment: I've always know this as just "von Neumann's inequality", possibly interesting: it can be extended to polynomials of two variables (Ando) but not to any more than two (Varopoulos).

Comment: The inequality shows that the so-called functional calculus is continuous from a normed space of polynomials into the operator algebra.  Such results can then be used to extend the functional calculus to more general classes of functions, often a crucial step in proofs of spectral representations.  For example,  a standard proof of the spectral theorem for  self-adjoint operators is based on a variant and can be extended to the non-bounded case by using more sophisticated  machinery.  Your example plays a role in the topic of functional calculus for non completely unitary contractions.